# How to run a Maven / Gradle web project through command line?

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven, gradle

I'm a beginner in Spring. I'm trying to find a command to execute a java web project created with gradle/maven and couldn't find a way. I want to do what eclipse does when I hit the "run on server" button.

For eg. in Django all i'll have to do is python3 manage.py runserver

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring-boot, [Spring Boot Maven Plugin](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-maven-plugin.html) allows you to package and run your application by using the following command:

> mvn spring-boot:run

Remember to include the spring-boot-maven-plugin inside your `pom.xml` as mentioned.

```
<build>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Read up on [Running as a Package Application](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-running-your-application.html) on how to run with Gradle Plugin.
Additional resources [See here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/).